# Обнуляется state без обращения React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В конструкторе объявляю `state`:

```
data: this.shuffle(this.newMassiv(25))
```

[image]

В *componentWillMount*, *componentDidMount* и *render* вызываю `console.log(this.state.data)`.
Как видно, в `didmount` массив обнуляется.
`state.data` нигде не изменяется.

Почему `state.data` обнуляется?
Пробовал задавать значение в *componentWillMount* - тоже самое.

Comment: Смотрите код по ходу текста.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно знать, когда будет вызван тот или иной метод.

- [`constructor`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) - конструктор для компонента React вызывается до его монтирования. Конструктор - это правильное место для инициализации состояния (`state`). Конструктор также часто используется для привязки обработчиков событий к экземпляру класса.
- [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) - вызывается непосредственно перед монтированием компонента и его отрисовкой (другими словами рендером - `render()`). Не рекомендуется вызвать метод `setState` внутри этого метода, обычно для инициализации стэйта используют конструктор (`constructor`). Данный метод считается небезопасным. Внутри него нет возможности посмотреть или обратиться к DOM элементам.
- [`render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) - обязательный метод, сам рендеринг компонента. Код данного метода должен быть чист, что означает, что он не изменяет состояние компонента. Метод должен возвращать один и тот же результат при каждом вызове и не взаимодействует напрямую с браузером.
- [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) - вызывается сразу после монтирования компонента. Обычно используется для загрузки данных через запросы или место для настройки подписки на события. Если нужно что-то сделать с DOM-элементами, то лучше здесь, вызывается после отрисовки, а значит после `render`. Вызов `setState` в этом методе вызовет дополнительный рендеринг, но это произойдет до того, как браузер обновит экран. Это гарантирует, что даже если `render()` будет вызываться дважды в этом случае, пользователь не увидит промежуточное состояние.

Последовательность вызова методов такая:

1. `constructor`
2. `componentWillMount`
3. `render`
4. `componentDidMount`

Если в `constructor` присвоить в `state` какое-то значение и это значение есть в методе `componentWillMount` и `render`, но нет в `componentDidMount`, значит значение `state` обновляется где-то в недрах вашего `render`. Возможно вы передаете ваш `state` в дочерние элементы и меняете его там - такое тоже возможно. Не видя полного кода - нельзя дать конкретный ответ. Необходимо внимательно посмотреть на код и найти место, где значение меняется. Не бывает так, что до метода `componentDidMount` не пришел `state`.